# PyQt5 Erro ao installar PyQtWebEngine

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt-5

Olá, estava tentando criar um browser com python e quando eu instalei o PyQtWebEngine, meu Pyqt5 parou de pegar e não funciona mais, ele mostro um erro de compatibilidade porem não conseguir resolver, ja tentei mexer no Path porem sem sucesso.

log da instalação :

```
λ pip3 install PyQtWebEngine
Collecting PyQtWebEngine
  Using cached PyQtWebEngine-5.14.0-5.14.1-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-none-win32.whl (47.9 MB)
Collecting PyQt5>=5.14
  Using cached PyQt5-5.14.1-5.14.1-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-none-win32.whl (45.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.7 in c:\users\sheep\appdata\local\program
s\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from PyQtWebEngine) (12.7.1)

ERROR: pyqt5-tools 5.13.2.1.6rc1 has requirement pyqt5==5.13.2, but you'll have pyqt5 5.14
.1 which is incompatible.

Installing collected packages: PyQt5, PyQtWebEngine
  Attempting uninstall: PyQt5
    Found existing installation: PyQt5 5.13.2
    Uninstalling PyQt5-5.13.2:
      Successfully uninstalled PyQt5-5.13.2
Successfully installed PyQt5-5.14.1 PyQtWebEngine-5.14.0
```

erro ao tentar executar o um arquivo com PyQt5:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.pyw", line 5, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: %1 não é um aplicativo Win32 válido.
```

Qual melhor maneira de resolver isso ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido usando o comando da seguinte maneira: `pip3 install PyQtWebEngine==5.13.2`